# CSS Animation of span with position right: auto to right: 0 won't animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I have a span that is positioned absolutely in a div.  The span is wider than the div, with an overflow of hidden, so I want to animate the span to the position `right: 0;` similar to a marquee effect.

How do I get it to slide from the starting position, to the position of `right: 0;`?

#### CSS

```
.auto-option__name-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    @include font-paragraph;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 1.618em;
    width: 11em;
    background-color: red;
}

.animateLongName{
    -webkit-animation: marquee 2s ease-in-out infinite;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0%    { right: auto; }
    100%  { right: 0px; }
  }
```

#### HTML

```
<body> 
 <div class="auto-option__name-container">
     <span class="animateLongName">
         This is a really long name that won't fit in the div
     </span>
 </div>
</body>
```

## JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WM9nQ/16/

Answer (score 1):

As Far I know you can't animate using an `auto` value. One option can be use `transform` property instead. Check this:

```css
.auto-option__name-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  @include font-paragraph;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 1.618em;
  width: 11em;
  background-color: red;
}
.animateLongName {
  -webkit-animation: marquee 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="auto-option__name-container">
  <span class="animateLongName">
         This is a really long name that won't fit in the div
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct; [auto animations](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transition-properties/) will not work, since auto is an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery animate:

```
var longName = $(".animateLongName");

var parent = longName.parent();
var difference = parent.width() - longName.width();
var margin = 10;

function animateSpan() {

   longName.animate({ left: difference-margin}, { duration: 5000, complete: function(){animateSpanBack()} });

}

function animateSpanBack() {

   longName.animate({ left: margin}, { duration: 5000, complete: function(){animateSpan()} });

}

if (difference < 0)  animateSpan();
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WM9nQ/18/

Answer (score 0):

I have made the animation working. 
 **Note:** I have used `:after` selector to hide the overflowing text; refer the `css` style.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nvishnu/WM9nQ/29/